# Using Core and Lwt together

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-lwt, ocaml-core

I am using Core and Lwt together in a library I am working on. Core has good modules I'm familiar with and I'm more comfortable with Lwt threads.

Is this a common thing to do? Is there any strong reason not to do that and instead use, let's say, only Core or only Lwt+Batteries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fine. I do it all the time. I wrote the [Future](https://github.com/agarwal/future) library, so I don't have to choose between Lwt and Async. However, be warned there are subtle differences in the semantics of Async and Lwt, so I won't recommend Future for very tricky concurrency code.

Answer (score 1):

`Core` works fine with `Lwt` to my experience. Although, I personally think that `Async` is more powerful, but `Lwt` is easier to start with, but on a long run you may found yourself reimplementing stuff from `Async`. It should mentioned, that `lwt` has a significant advantage in comparison with `async` it works on windows and js. But if doesn't matter for you, I would personally suggest to use `Async`.